# How do we print django models object value?

Tags: python, django

> Hello, everyone! So, I create models in `models.py` file of my django
>   project and controllers in `views.py` . I wrote a function called
>   `register(request)` that add a new user to my database and another
>   called `login(request)` that verifies if the datas sent by the user are in my
>   db to log him in. Brief, the problem is when I want to print the user's first name
>   in my template, it shows to me the object in string ...
>
> Here is the `login(request)` function:

```
def login(request):

    title = 'Connexion'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        email_sent = request.POST['email']
        password_sent = request.POST['password'].encode('utf-8')

        global isConnected

        user = Users.objects.filter(email = email_sent)

        if user and bcrypt.checkpw(password_sent, user[0].password):
            if isConnected in request.session:
                isConnected = request.session['isConnected']
                return redirect('http://localhost:8000/', 
                                {'isConnected':isConnected, 
                                 'first_name':user[0].first_name, 
                                 'last_name':user[0].first_name})

            else:
                request.session['id'] =user[0].first_name
                request.session['first_name'] = user[0].first_name
                request.session['last_name'] = user[0].first_name
                request.session['phone'] = user[0].first_name
                isConnected = True

                return redirect('http://localhost:8000/', 
                                {'isConnected':isConnected, 
                                 'first_name':user[0].first_name })

        else:
            print('Something went wrong')
            return render(request, 'login.html', 
                          {'title':title, 'isConnected':isConnected})

        return render(request, 'login.html', 
                      {'title':title, 'isConnected':isConnected})

    else:

        return render(request, 'login.html', 
                      {'title':title, 'isConnected':isConnected })
```

Here is what I represent the user's first_name variable in my template:

```
<span class="initials" style="...">{{ first_name }}</span>
```

And that is it prints to me:

```
<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x0000017850EE7A00>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would help a lot to post just a minumal reproducible example. However, there are so many issues with this code it is better to post to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use .first() end of your query as:

```
   user = Users.objects.filter(email = email_sent).first()
```

so you have the first object and don't need to slicing. remember that Django queries are lazy.